# How to use URLs that contain ampersands (&) with phpTumb?

Tags: php, phpthumb

Let's say I have the following URL: `pic.php?t=1&p=23`
When I try `phpThumb.php?src=/pic.php?t=1&p=23`, I get `Forbidden parameter: p`.
Anyone knows if there's a way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URLEncode that ampersand if you are trying to pass `p=23` to `pic.php`. Try replacing the `&` with `%26`.

What you are effectively doing there is passing `p=23` as a parameter to `phpThumb.php`, which obviously it doesn't like...

What you probably want to do is `'phpThumb.php?src='.urlencode('/pic.php?t=1&p=23');`

Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 0):

[`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/urlencode) the URL before passing it to phpThumb.

Answer (score 0):

You can URL encode the ampersand to make it part of the content of the parameter in the querystring. This way, the whole `/pic.php?t=1&p=23` gets passed as the `src`.

```
phpThumb.php?src=/pic.php?t=1%26p=23
```

The `%26` is the encoded version of the `&`.

Use [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/urlencode).